# Hanging on Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action) when unit tesing

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, caliburn.micro

I'm writing unit tests for view models. The app is written using Caliburn.Micro for MVVM support. Many view models depend on Application.Current.Dispatcher with intention to dispatch some code into the UI thread.

To create the Application object from within the tests I have written the following class:

```
public class AppInitializer {
    private static Application app;
    public static void InitApp() {
        app = app ?? (app = Application.Current ?? new Application());
    }
}
```

Now I just do the following in each test class:

```
[ClassInitialize]
    public static void InitClass(TestContext ctx) {
        AppInitializer.InitApp();
    }
```

Unfortunately, the first call to Application.Current.Dispatcher from within a view model hangs my tests until timeout will be reached.

I don't want to abstract somehow the Application.CurrentDispatcher, I don't want to pass into view models one more mocked object. I want to get some workaround if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the call to `Application.Run`. You're right that one of the `Application` classes' responsibilities is to create and start a `Dispatcher` on the thread that it is currently executing on but all this happens during the call to `Run`.

And this is where the trouble begins: `Run` is a blocking call, i.e. your unit tests will not be executed until `Run` exits. In Store Apps, there is a special attribute called `UITestMethod` but I don't think that it is available in WPF (especially if you are not using MSTest).

So what are your options? You could create the application on a different thread than the one your unit tests run on - but this will result in method calls to `Join` as you have to look if your call was dispatched to the other thread. This is potential for slow unit tests.

You even cannot create a dispatcher manually on the thread your unit tests are executed on - because it is the same thing as mentioned before with the `App` class: `Dispatcher.Run` is a blocking call.

That's why I would advise you to create an abstraction for `Dispatcher` and inject it - it's saves you a lot of pain.

**Update for Ambient Context:**

In the comments, I mentioned the Ambient Context as a solution that does not rely on injecting an object into view models that conforms to the `Dispatcher` abstraction. This is how it would look like in code:

```cs
public interface IDispatcher
{
    void ExecuteOnUIThread(Action action);
    // Add whatever methods you need on this interface
}

public static class DispatcherContext
{
    // An instance that implements IDispatcher can be accessed via this static property
    public static IDispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }
}

// Of course you need to write an adapter for the WPF Dispatcher class
```

This way you can create a dispatcher mock for your unit tests but still be able to access this via a static property in your view models. You can learn more about this pattern on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx or in Mark Seemann's excellent book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501).

Comment: If I add app.Run(), a test hangs on this call.

Comment: Sorry I was not finished with my answer yet. I've updated it.

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately, I use everywhere Caliburn's static method Execute.OnUITread(Action action). That will be hard to mock.

Comment: Which unit testing framework do you use? Do you know if it maybe supports creating the Dispatcher for you?

Comment: I use mstest. I don't know yet whether it supports such a feature.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Well, if you want to keep on unit testing (which I would really advise you to do), you will have to create an abstraction. If you don't want to inject this into your view models, you can also use an Ambient Context (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx) which basically is an object that can be accessed via a static property with an interface type. But I would really advise to inject this object into your view models that need it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you an abstract example for the ambient context pattern.